# Automatic Level Generation from Array

Tags: actionscript-3, math

So, I am trying to make the stages for the level in my game automatically generated.
I made an array (note, the amount of "tiles" on the screen is 16x16):

```
var background:Array=new Array(
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
)
```

And as you can probably tell, each 1 or 0 corresponds to if the tile is one thing or another (there or not there in this scenario).

I am pretty bad at the next part that I did.

I decided to make this using http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-create-a-platform-game-in-as3-part-2/'s method (kinda).

```
var bkgblocks:Sprite=new Sprite();
var bkgblocksw:Number=stage.stageWidth/16
var bkgblocksh:Number=stage.stageHeight/16

//the blocks are 45 pixels wide and tall

var row:int=0;
for(var i:int=0; i<background.length;i++){
    if((i+1)/16==int((i+1)/16)){
        //if i is divisible by 16
        row++
    }
    if(background[i]==1){
        bkgblocks.graphics.beginFill(0x000000)
        bkgblocks.graphics.drawRect(I have no idea what to do here ,row*stage.stageHeight/16,bkgblocksw,bkgblocksh); 
        bkgblocks.graphics.endFill()
        addChild(bkgblocks)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have no idea how or where to place the blocks!

I have where to place their y coordinate, but the x is way too confusing.

I thought I could do something like this

```
i*(45/(row+1))
```

but that messed up completely. This is more of a math question, I'm sorry, but if anybody can (or has) figure this out, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I usually prefer packing a grid into an array of arrays to make it more human-readable e. g.

```
var grid:Array = [
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
   [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
];
```

Where the first (outer) array contains rows of cells, each row represented by an array
So you can access a cell by calling `grid[y][x]` and find the 'real' coordinates by multiplying `x` and `y` by `const CELL_SIZE`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are tangled with 1D-2D coordinate transformation.

Let's width of your screen (2D coordinates) is `Wdt`. So element with (x,y) coordinates will be at `y * Wdt + x` index of 1D array.

```
A[y * Wdt + x]  corresponds to Screen[y][x]
```

And back tranform:

```
 x = index %% Wdt   //integer modulus
 y = index \ Wdt    //integer division

 Screen[index \ Wdt] [index %% Wdt] = A[index]
```